# Asymptotic behaviour of function deduced from equation involving integrals, logs, and weights $1/t$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analytic-number-theory

I don't really know what the title of this question should be, but here's my question:

Notation: $\ll $ and $\mathcal O$ is the usual "Big Oh" notation, see e.g. the "formal definitions" section of the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

Take a continuous function $f\ll 1$ and write
\[ E(x)=f(x)\log x-\int _2^x\frac {f(t)dt}{t}.\hspace {10mm}(1)\]
**Why does
\[ E(x)\ll 1\]
imply an asymptotic for $f$?**  (And $1$ could be replaced by something greater so long as it's a bit smaller than $\log x$). In fact it implies
\[ f(x)=c+\mathcal O\left (\frac {1}{\log x}\right )\]
where
\[ c=c_f=\int _2^\infty \frac {E(x)dx}{x(\log x)^2}.\]
Here is the argument:

Divide $(1)$ through by $x(\log x)^2$ and integrate.  After switching around the double integral, this gives us
\[ \int _2^X\frac {f(x)dx}{x\log x}-\int _2^X\frac {f(t)}{t}\left (\int _t^X\frac {dx}{x(\log x)^2}\right )dt=c-\int _X^\infty \frac {E(x)dx}{x(\log x)^2}.\]
The inner $dx$ integral is
\[ \frac {1}{\log t}-\frac {1}{\log X}\]
so we are left with
\[ \frac {1}{\log X}\int _{2}^X\frac {f(t)dt}{t}=c+\mathcal O\left (\frac {1}{\log x}\right )\]
and now the claim follows from
\[ f(X)=\frac {1}{\log X}\int _{2}^X\frac {f(t)dt}{t}+\mathcal O\left (\frac {|E(x)|}{\log X}\right ).\]

I'm not really sure what kind of answer I'm looking for, since obviously a proof says "why".  But I just feel there's a hand-wavey intuition that I'm missing which supports the statement that
\[ f(x)\log x\sim \int _2^x\frac {f(t)dt}{t}\implies f(x)\sim c.\]

I'm aware of "smoothing arguments" (if that's what happens here) when only sums are concerned.  For example, I have no ill-feelings about statements like
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}a_n\log (x/n)\sim c\hspace {5mm}\text { or }\hspace {5mm}\sum _{n\leq x}a_n(1-n/x)\sim c\]
should imply the same for the unweighted sum.  (Probably because statements like "for $n$ close to $x$ the weights become closer to constants").  But maybe it's really not the same thing and that's irrelevant.

I could provide context for the question but I feel it's a bit long already.  It comes from something I was reading in number theory, so I'll tag that, but feel free to add or remove tags, or to demand more context.

Comment: What is the definition of $f\ll1$?

Comment: added a link for the formal definition.  but it basically means $f$ is bounded.  and $\mathcal O(g(x))$ means a quantity bounded by $g(x)$

Comment: Note that $c$ is the integral of $E(x)/(x\log^2 x)$ up to $+\infty$ and not just up to $X$. It should be replaced by $c+\mathcal{O}(1/\log X)$.

Comment: thanks! edited.

Comment: I do not see any reason for that. Note that for example if $f(x)=\log\log x$, then $$
f(x)\log x \sim \int_2^x {\frac{{f(t)}}{t}dt} 
$$ is still true. In this case of course $E(x) =\mathcal{O} (\log x)$, so $E(x) \ll 1$ does not hold.